# Best approach to save multiple types of objects in the same table?

Tags: java, database, oracle, workflow

What is the best approach to save multiple objects of different types in the same table?

Production database is Oracle 10g. please note limitations with this old version.

Here is the problem, there is an workflow management solution on going. In this, there are several workflows, users can send a request and after several approval stages, it gets an approval. 
The problem is saving and updating these multiple requests. Using different tables is not viable option since new workflows will be introduced in the future and I need to implement a common way to handle multiple requests.

Comment: If I got your question right, look at XMLType.

Comment: why XML type? why not JSON type?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher - because Oracle 10g has capabilities for working with XML, including the ability to index XPath queries, whereas JSON support wasn't added until 12c?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've created a false dilemma about schema design.  Your choice isn't between one infinitely-generic God table versus an infinite number of small hard-coded tables.

Yes, a good database design requires more than one table to represent anything in the real world.  But that doesn't mean you have to create a new table for every type.  You have to think about your problem and create tables that can accommodate future some future changes.

Without knowing more specifics, I'd recommend you look into these ideas, in order:

1. **Relational** - Plain old tables are capable of representing generic workflows.  I've seen tables handle that scenario many times before.  Relational tables won't work if you hard-code the columns for the workflows, like creating columns named `OPEN_DATE`, `CLOSE_DATE`, and `APPEAL_DATE`.  But if you make your schema a bit smarter, and create columns like `ID`, `WORKFLOW_TYPE_ID`, and `START_DATE`, it should work fine.
2. **Relational with EAV** - If you need flexibility for the data associated with workflows you might want to look into the Entity-Attribute-Value pattern.  The simple version is a table with columns like `ID`, `NAME`, `STRING_VALUE`, `NUMBER_VALUE`, `DATE_VALUE`.  These tables are sometimes necessary, but can be difficult to work with for complex data.  Use them sparingly.
3. **XML** - If you truly have an infinitely flexible data model (narrator: you don't), then you can store everything as XML.  Oracle's XML capabilities are quite thorough, if you're willing to invest the time learning it.
4. **Object-Relational** - A terrible option, in my opinion, but theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either XMLTYPE or JSON. But JSON support was given after Oracle 12c.
[How to use JSON](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/json-support-in-oracle-database-12cr1)

So in order to be used with Oracle 10g you can use XMLTYPE.
[How to Use the XMLTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm)